# Do I need to release the context returned from UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am using `CGContextRef`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);
CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Do I need to call `CGContextRelease(Context);` in the above one.

Comment: This is your 12th post on SO. Please have a look at the formatting docs: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Then why are getting a leak in that and how to remove it?

Answer (score 28):

No.

See [The Create Rule vs. The Get Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029):

> #### The Create Rule
>
> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a returned object:
>
> Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
>   Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name.
>
> [...]
>
> #### The Get Rule
>
> If you receive an object from any Core Foundation function other than a creation or copy function—such as a Get function—you do not own it [...]